# Intensity of spectral lines

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, atoms, intensity

Why are certain spectral lines more intense than others, that is why certain transitions between levels have greater probabilities of occurrence than others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transition probability between two levels is given by the Fermi golden rule:
$$w_{i\rightarrow f} = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|V_{i,f}|^2\delta(E_i - E_f \pm \hbar\omega).$$
Thus, the principal factor that determines the intensity of a transition is the matrix element, $V_{i,f}$, which is different for different levels. Frequently one deals with the dipolar coupling
$$\hat{V} = - \mathbf{d}\cdot\mathbf{E},$$ where the dipolar matrix element is given by
$$\mathbf{d}_{i,f} = \int d^3\mathbf{r}\psi_i(\mathbf{r})^*\mathbf{r}\psi_f(\mathbf{r}),
$$
which is obviously different for the different pairs of the states $i, f$.

Another reason for different line intensity is different final density of states of the background radiation that causes the spontaneous emission.